# Minimize Internet access for Bluemix Local

Tags: local, ibm-cloud

My customer wants to have Bluemix Local on their isolated DC from pulic.
They have a policy not to have internet access on the DC. Only allow to connect to internet in a limited period of time based on the IT/LOB request.

I know that the Bluemix Local need to have internet connection with IBM site for the purpose of the Remote maintenance by IBM.

Question:

Is it possible to minimize the on-line time between the Bluemix Local and IBM site ?  The customer wants it offline normally and online only at the event of maintenance.

Thank you for your support.
Kohzo

Comment: Sure. Contact your Bluemix local tech seller to arrange.

Answer (score 2):

The component that allow Bluemix local  to be managed by IBM operation team is called "Relay".
Relay achieves secure connectivity through an open, outbound SSL, VPN tunnel that originates from the inception virtual machine on-premises by using certificates that are specific to each Bluemix Local instance.
The traffic on this tunnel is automated activity for serving and maintaining the platform, compute resources, and services for your instance. The traffic includes the monitoring capability that is used by IBM operations to complete problem determination for your local instance.
Only the IBM team that is working on local environment can securely access  Bluemix instance. Access to ocal environment is secured by using two-factor authentication during multiple steps in the connection process. IBM provides a list of the approved users and IDs who can access the environment, and then customer can audit any access to the environment. 
Since if a network interruption occurs Relay automatically re-establishes the  connection, it does mean that the Relay must be always up .

Comment: Information about Bluemix Local and Relay is available at this URL: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/local/index.html#localarch